# H2db Error org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "Chunk not found"

Tags: java, h2

I have recently migrated h2db from version 1.X to version 2.X with the below steps

```
Step1) java -cp h2-1.4.192.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./h2db -script migrate.sql
```

Some alters in migrate.sql.

```
Step2) java -cp h2-1.4.192.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:./h2db -script h2db.zip -options compression zip

Step3) java -cp h2-2.1.212.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./h2db -script h2db.zip -options compression zip FROM_1X
```

All works well and the application was started and running fine. My application uses the latest version of h2db 2.1.214 while the h2db.mv.db file was created with version 2.1.212. I restarted the application and suddenly I got the below error while it was creating the cached table. Also I tried to connect H2db with h2 console and got the same error. Screenshot attached. This issue occurs on customer production environment and now customer is not able to access the application.

[image]

Error which I am getting is when h2db file created with version 2.1.212 and also accessed by the same version

```
Exception in thread "main" **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "Chunk 849734 not found [2.1.212/9]"; SQL statement:**
CREATE CACHED TABLE "PUBLIC"."ABC_XYZ"(
    "ID" BIGINT SELECTIVITY 100 NOT NULL,
    "MACHINE_ID" BIGINT SELECTIVITY 1,
    "WHEN_CREATED" BIGINT SELECTIVITY 100 NOT NULL,
    "STATE" INTEGER SELECTIVITY 1,
    "WHEN_STATE_LAST_CHANGED" BIGINT SELECTIVITY 1,
    "WHO_CHANGED_STATE_LAST" BIGINT SELECTIVITY 1
) [50000-212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:554)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.convertMVStoreException(Store.java:170)
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.Store.createTable(Store.java:220)
        at org.h2.schema.Schema.createTable(Schema.java:781)
        at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:109)
        at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.prepareAndExecute(MetaRecord.java:77)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.executeMeta(Database.java:660)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.executeMeta(Database.java:634)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:357)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:92)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)
        at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:288)
        at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:270)
        at org.h2.tools.Shell.runTool(Shell.java:146)
        at org.h2.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:80)
Caused by: org.h2.mvstore.MVStoreException: Chunk 849734 not found [2.1.212/9]
```

Comment: If you cannot quickly fix-forward then perhaps the solution is to reverse your migration, and test the migration more fully in a nonprod environment.

Comment: Reversing migration means coming back to V1.x from V2.x of h2db we have already released V2.x in our application and many of our customers have migrated to the newer version. Also, V1.x has listed vulnerabilities i.e. we have done this migration.

Comment: Well, I accept that you regard the migration as done, but this may be the consequences of undertaking a migration without fully testing it first. You can fix forward, but that may mean several days of downtime. The error appears to be arcane and, assuming you have already thoroughly researched the error, it may not be a trivially solveable problem.

Comment: I have no specific expertise here, but there are some generally applicable fixes. Did you do a full database dump in the old version and a full database import in the new version? I wonder if there is a binary format incompatibility, and the migrate operation in your question is insufficient.

Comment: Do you have any commercial support for H2 that you can call upon?

Comment: Yes the migration was done with great care. If there is any incompatibility then h2 would not have allowed the migration process to be successful. No i don't have any commercial support but i have raised this question on h2 github but still didn't find any solution.

https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3662

Apologise for the late response.

Comment: Maybe you could get some consulting for H2 - either your account manager might be able to recommend someone, or you could find a consulting platform like AirPair, and pay on an hourly basis.

Comment: I also suggested a full dump and restore, that might be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will ask the same.